# Split string into dictionary with space delimiter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python string like this

```
query = 'name:Thoong company:"Big Company, LLC" age:25'
```

I want convert it to a dictionary with key and value split by ':'

```
{
    'name': 'Thoong',
    'age': 25,
    'company': 'Big Company, LLC',
}
```

I tried to split by `' '` and then `':'`. but seems the `query.split(' ')` not work because we have `' '` `"Big Company, LLC"`

Is there any way to archive this, could be using a regular expression?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shlex.html):

```
import shlex

dict(i.split(":") for i in shlex.split(query))
```

Output:

```
{'age': '25', 'company': 'Big Company, LLC', 'name': 'Thoong'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use regex and insert into a dictionary:

```
import re

regex_1 = r"(\w+:\w+)"
regex_2 = r"(\w+:\"\w+\s\w+,\s\w+\")"
query = 'name:Thoong company:"Big Company, LLC" age:25'
r_1 = re.findall(regex_1, query)
r_2 = re.search(regex_2, query).group(1)
d = {*r_1,
     r_2}

print(d)
```

Returning:

```
{'name:Thoong', 'age:25', 'company:"Big Company, LLC"'}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?
This looks not elegant but you can easily understand what this code does.

```
query = 'name:Thoong company:"Big Company, LLC" age:25'
tmp = query.split(":")
keys = []
values = []

# extract keys
for t in tmp:
    _t = t.split(" ")
    if len(_t) == 1:
        keys.append(_t[0])
    else:
        values.append(" ".join(_t[:-1]))
        keys.append(t.split(" ")[-1])

values.append(keys[-1])
del keys[-1]
result = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting on blanks ( ) and other signs probably won't work as names may contain any number of characters.

If the query always consists of these three elements, you could try splitting at the keywords:

```
d = {'name': query.split('name:')[1].split(' company:')[0],
     'company': query.split('company:')[1].split(' age:')[0],
     'age': query.split('age:')[1]}
```

If the query is ill formatted, though, this will not work. There, you might have to try to parse it and escape the blanks and colons that occur within quotation marks.